# iOS - Custom UIToolbar - aligning one UiBarButtonItem left, another right

Tags: alignment, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbaritem

I am creating a custom toolbar for a small chat application which has a camera button, a textfield and a send button. All of the functionality is working, but I am stuck with trying to get the Send button position.

The camera button needs to be aligned on the left, while the send button needs to be aligned on the right.

I am getting this to kind of work, but can not get the send button to align to the right side properly, I cannot seem to move it further right than what it is at this point.

I have tried flexible spacing along with fixed spacing (which is currently in my code snippet) with no success.

```
NSString *imageValue = @"btnCamera.png";
UIImage *cameraImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageValue];
UIButton *cameraButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cameraButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 49);
[cameraButton setImage:cameraImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:cameraButton];
[cameraButton addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(inputCamButtonPressed)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
spacer.width = -12;
[items addObject:spacer];
[items addObject:cameraItem];

UIBarButtonItem *fixedItemSpaceWidth = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

fixedItemSpaceWidth.width = screenWidth - 90; 
[items addObject:fixedItemSpaceWidth];

imageValue = @"send.png";
UIImage *sendImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageValue];
UIButton *sendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
sendButton.enabled = NO;
sendButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
sendButton.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 49);
[sendButton setImage:sendImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *sendItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:sendButton];
sendItem.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];

/* Create UIExpandingTextView input */
self.textView = [[BHExpandingTextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 7, self.bounds.size.width - 70, 26)];
self.textView.internalTextView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f);
self.textView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.textView.delegate = self;
[self addSubview:self.textView];

[self setItems:items animated:NO];
```

[image]

Hoping someone maybe able to spot the most likely silly little mistake I am making and can't get around.